# What is the definite integral of the function $f(x)=x\csc(x)$ from $0$ to $1$?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, definite-integrals, change-of-variable

A simple question, but I can't seem to find the answer. I want to calculate the definite integral of the function $f(x)=x\cdot\csc(x)$ from $0$ to $1$:

$$\int_0^1 x\csc(x)\, dx. $$

And from there, calculate the same integral, but with $x^3\csc(x)$,  $x^4\csc(x)$, and $x^6\csc(x)$.

I'm almost convinced it's impossible, but my professor suggested to use the change of variable $u=\tan(\frac{x}{2})$. Is there any way to calculate these integrals?

Comment: Are your bounds correct?  The answer is not nice at all.

Comment: @Ty. ... I see what you mean.  $$\int_0^{\pi/2} x \csc x\;dx = 2G$$ where $G$ is Catalan's constant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant

Comment: @Ty. Yes, the 0 and 1 bounds are correct. I was able to get the integral of csc(x), quite easy, but i can't calculate x·csc(x). My professor says i should be able to calculate it by parts, but i think that's not possible.

Answer (score 2):

One can evaluate this in the following way:
$$\int _0^1\frac{x}{\sin \left(x\right)}\:dx$$
By using Weierstrass sub we get:
$$\int _0^{\tan \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}\frac{2\arctan \left(t\right)}{\frac{2}{1+t^2}}\:\frac{2}{t^2+1}dt=2\int _0^{\tan \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}\frac{\arctan \left(t\right)}{t}\:dt$$
$$=2\:\text{Ti}_2\left(\tan \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)\approx1.059762$$
Where i used the inverse tangent integral identity, see [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseTangentIntegral.html) for more info.